# How to use browserSync() of elixir in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I am using elixir() of Laravel `5.2`,this is `gulpfile.js`:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-sass-compass');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.compass(['app.scss', 'controllers.scss']).version('css/app.css');
    mix.scripts(['jquery.js','app.js']).version('js/all.js');
});
```

I want to add `browserSync()` into `gulpfile.js`,
Where should I put it?

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserSync({ 
       proxy: 'project.app'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I put it?

It could be anywhere inside you gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-sass-compass');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.compass(['app.scss', 'controllers.scss']).version('css/app.css');
    mix.scripts(['jquery.js','app.js']).version('js/all.js');
    mix.browserSync({ 
       proxy: 'project.app'
    });
});
```

Then, run `gulp watch` and watch your browser syncing front-end file you were changing in `http://project.app:3000`

Answer (score 1):

I got it working on my new laravel 5.2 project via the following steps:

1. npm install
2. npm install laravel-elixir-browser-sync --save-dev
3. change the gulpfile.js to read

   ```
   var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
   elixir(function(mix) {
       mix.sass('app.scss');
       mix.browserSync({
           proxy: 'app.local',
           files: [
               'app/**/*',
               'public/**/*',
               'resources/**/*'
           ]
       });
   });
   ```
4. run "gulp watch"